# Mixing Access 64-bit clients with Access 32-bit clients

Tags: ms-access, vba, 32bit-64bit

We are building an Access database application. The data will also be stored in an Access file, although obviously we'll be be splitting front end and back end.

The guy I'm working with has 64-bit Office 2013 installed on his Windows 7 PC, and requires it for the very large Excel files he's working with. Our database will essentially extract data from these spreadsheets and import it into various tables within the database.

However, there are various other people who will need to use the database. They're all using 32-bit Office 2013.

Will this cause a problem? Has anyone any experience of developing for a mixed environment like this? Can it even be done, or will the application developed on a 64-bit version of office fail to compile when on a 32-bit office PC?

Answer (score 0):

The `accdb` is the same, the only difference will be that if your code includes calls to the API, that code must adopt to the 32- or 64-bit environment using `PtrSafe`. Just Google/Bing on this if this is relevant for your application.